# The combusation temperature of hydrogen and oxygen

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, physical-chemistry

Suppose we have in a closed and insulated chamber $2$ mol Hydrogen and 1 mol oxygen, so that they can burn into 2 mol water.

Suppose initially the temperature of the system is $T_i$. After the reaction, what is the temperature of the water vapor?

Is the process entropy conserving?

Comment: What are your initial thoughts on approaching the problem? It isn't clear what you don't understand.

Comment: I want to calculate the temperature (presumably very high) of the water vapor after the reaction

Comment: Could you show your effort?